# Springboot demo application doesn't get deployed correctly on Wildfly

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly

i'm following [this tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/spring/spring-boot-hello-world-on-wildfly) to learn how to deploy a basic spring boot application on wildfly.
The application runs correctly using the embedded tomcat server, but it doesn't work on wildfly. I do not see any spring boot related log on my eclipse console, it seems like the spring boot framework is not even loaded on wildfly.

This is the main (and only) java class:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloworldApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloworldApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<HelloworldApplication> applicationClass = HelloworldApplication.class;
}

@RestController
class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
    String hello(@PathVariable String name) {

             return "Hi "+name+" !";

    }
}
```

and this is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <relativePath />
      <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>helloworld</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <finalName>springbootwildfly</finalName>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>spring-snapshots</id>
         <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
         <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
         </snapshots>
      </repository>
      <repository>
         <id>spring-milestones</id>
         <name>Spring Milestones</name>
         <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
         </snapshots>
      </repository>
   </repositories>
   <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
         <id>spring-snapshots</id>
         <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
         <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
         </snapshots>
      </pluginRepository>
      <pluginRepository>
         <id>spring-milestones</id>
         <name>Spring Milestones</name>
         <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
         </snapshots>
      </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

This is the relevant part of the eclipse console log:

```
15:54:57,852 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
15:54:57,868 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
15:54:57,875 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
15:54:57,956 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/kyc]
15:54:57,979 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
15:54:58,255 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
15:54:58,318 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.3.0.Final (Apache CXF 3.3.3) 
15:55:00,042 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
15:55:00,043 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
15:55:00,045 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
15:55:00,047 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
15:55:00,051 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
15:55:00,150 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-5) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Infinity Minus ONE +2' 9.4.16.Final
15:55:00,465 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
15:55:00,628 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
15:55:00,665 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.9.SP04 for context '/helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
15:55:01,579 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' for server 'default-server'
15:55:01,677 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
15:55:01,744 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
15:55:01,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
15:55:01,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
15:55:01,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 18.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) started in 7452ms - Started 540 of 766 services (375 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

I'm using eclipse 20-03, wildfly 18.0.1 and spring boot 2.2.6, what am i missing here?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: my pom.xml raises a warning about the javax.servlet dependency, telling me that i'm overriding the managed version defined among the spring-boot-dependencies.

Comment: I'll admit I'm no Springboot expert but why do you want to run an environment that has an embedded server or standalone environment - Springboot - on a server?  I thought Springboot is meant to stand on it's own and not *need* a container.

Comment: I'm not expert too, but the software i'm going to write needs to be deployed on a wildfly application server, so i'm experimenting with it :)

Comment: the WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007 look like something to investigate

Comment: Looks like it{s deployed, but it doesn't start the reactive component, you must enable your logger on DEBUG level for more info, but anyway you can call your service since it´s deployed, so you can try probably {yourhostip}:{wildfly_port}/helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/hello/test for example

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below dependency in your pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

For more details check the following
[Update to Spring 5.1 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseBodyProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709747/update-to-spring-5-1-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-http)