# Error finding remote EJB with Spring Boot war app on Wildfly

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, wildfly, ejb-3.2

I would ultimately like to create a RESTful API that supports EJBs 3+, traditional HTTP requests, and eventually JPA/Hibernate.  I am using Eclipse version 2021-03, running a JBOSS Wildfly server, created a remote EJB using an interface (similar to [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-ejb)), and finally the REST API is made with Spring boot.

**Updated** - 4/22/2021

Based on the log output the remote EJB gets created and the RESTful routes work on the web server.  There is an entry in the client pom.xml for the EJB dependency and I am able to inject the EJB dependency however I am getting a naming exception during the lookup process.  I have checked the JNDI binding info multiple times however still getting an exception.  Any help would greatly appreciated.

---

### EJB Remote Code

HelloStatefulWorld.java

```
@Remote
public interface HelloStatefulWorld {

    int howManyTimes();
    String getHelloWorld();
}
```

HelloStatefulWorldEJB.java

```
@Stateful(name="HelloStatefulWorld")
public class HelloStatefulWorldEJB implements HelloStatefulWorld {

    private int howManyTimes = 0;

    public int howManyTimes() {
        return howManyTimes;
    }

    public String getHelloWorld() {
        howManyTimes++;
        return "Hello Stateful World!";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>swe642a4-ejb-remote</groupId>
    <artifactId>swe642a4-ejb-remote</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>
    <name>swe642a4-ejb-remote</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>ejbModule</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>ejbModule</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                    <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

### EJB Client Code/ REST API

ServletInitializer.java

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Swe642a4EjbClientApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Swe642a4EjbClientApplication.java

```
import com.mastertheboss.springboot.HelloStatefulWorld;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Swe642a4EjbClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Swe642a4EjbClientApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean   
    public Context context() throws NamingException {
        Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
        jndiProps.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        jndiProps.put("java.naming.provider.url", "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
        return new InitialContext(jndiProps);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public HelloStatefulWorld helloStatefulWorld(Context context) throws NamingException {
        return (HelloStatefulWorld) context.lookup(this.getFullName(HelloStatefulWorld.class));
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private String getFullName(Class classType) {
        String moduleName = "swe642a4-ejb-remote/";
        String beanName = classType.getSimpleName();
        String viewClassName = classType.getName();
        
        return moduleName + beanName + "!" + viewClassName;
    }

}

@RestController
class SurveyController{
    
    //private HelloStatefulWorld helloStatefulWorld;
    
    /*public SurveyController(HelloStatefulWorld helloStatefulWorld) {
        this.helloStatefulWorld = helloStatefulWorld;
    }*/
    
    @RequestMapping(path="/hello/{name}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    String hello(@PathVariable String name) {
         
             return "Hi "+name+" !";
    }
    
    /*@RequestMapping(path="/stateful", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getStateful() {
        return helloStatefulWorld.getHelloWorld() + " called " + helloStatefulWorld.howManyTimes() + " times";
    }*/
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mastertheboss.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>swe642a4-ejb-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>swe642a4-ejb-client</name>
    <description>EJB Client</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>swe642a4-ejb-remote</groupId>
            <artifactId>swe642a4-ejb-remote</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.1.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xnio-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>    
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>            
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>            
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

---

### Eclipse Log Output

```
11:54:24,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'HelloStatefulWorld' in deployment unit 'deployment "swe642a4-ejb-remote.jar"' are as follows:

    java:global/swe642a4-ejb-remote/HelloStatefulWorld!com.mastertheboss.springboot.HelloStatefulWorld
    java:app/swe642a4-ejb-remote/HelloStatefulWorld!com.mastertheboss.springboot.HelloStatefulWorld
    java:module/HelloStatefulWorld!com.mastertheboss.springboot.HelloStatefulWorld
    java:jboss/exported/swe642a4-ejb-remote/HelloStatefulWorld!com.mastertheboss.springboot.HelloStatefulWorld
    ejb:/swe642a4-ejb-remote/HelloStatefulWorld!com.mastertheboss.springboot.HelloStatefulWorld?stateful
    java:global/swe642a4-ejb-remote/HelloStatefulWorld
    java:app/swe642a4-ejb-remote/HelloStatefulWorld
    java:module/HelloStatefulWorld

11:54:24,597 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) WELD-000900: 3.1.6 (Final)
11:54:24,878 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Corona Extra' 11.0.9.Final
11:54:24,922 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (MSC service thread 1-5) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
11:54:24,924 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (MSC service thread 1-5) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
11:54:24,999 INFO  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.marshalling.InfinispanProtoStreamMarshaller'
11:54:25,194 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
11:54:25,196 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
11:54:25,199 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
11:54:25,199 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HttpHandlerAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
11:54:25,201 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
11:54:25,210 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) WFLYCLINF0002: Started http-remoting-connector cache from ejb container
11:54:25,390 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 91) 3 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
Handler java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is not defined
Handler java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is not defined
Handler java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is not defined
11:54:27,535 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) Application run failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloStatefulWorld' defined in com.mastertheboss.springboot.swe642a4ejbclient.Swe642a4EjbClientApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mastertheboss.springboot.HelloStatefulWorld]: Factory method 'helloStatefulWorld' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup swe642a4-ejb-remote/HelloStatefulWorld!com.mastertheboss.springboot.HelloStatefulWorld [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponentUnavailableException: WFLYEJB0467: The request was rejected as the container is suspended]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:204)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mastertheboss.springboot.HelloStatefulWorld]: Factory method 'helloStatefulWorld' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup swe642a4-ejb-remote/HelloStatefulWorld!com.mastertheboss.springboot.HelloStatefulWorld [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponentUnavailableException: WFLYEJB0467: The request was rejected as the container is suspended]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup swe642a4-ejb-remote/HelloStatefulWorld!com.mastertheboss.springboot.HelloStatefulWorld [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponentUnavailableException: WFLYEJB0467: The request was rejected as the container is suspended]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:159)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteServerTransport.handleLookup(RemoteServerTransport.java:203)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteServerTransport$1.handleMessage(RemoteServerTransport.java:123)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel.lambda$handleMessageData$3(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:430)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(EndpointImpl.java:991)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponentUnavailableException: WFLYEJB0467: The request was rejected as the container is suspended
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor$2$1.getReference(EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:273)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:143)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponentUnavailableException: WFLYEJB0467: The request was rejected as the container is suspended
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor$2$1.getReference(EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:265)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Since you're generating the EJB client, why not a dependency on `<type>ejb-client</type>` instead? Also, make sure the generated WAR includes the dependency in `/WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: I tried using <type>ejb-client</type> before but didn't seem to make a difference and a warning pops up that it is not fully supported.  This may be an eclipse anomaly so I will give it another try but after looking in my /WEB-INF/lib folder it shows the jar but no class files inside.  Should'nt I see the HelloStatefulWorld.class file as part of this?

Comment: I finally figured it out...well partially, the initial "ClassNotFound" error was due a dependency posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709747/update-to-spring-5-1-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-http), that one I still have no explanation for.  The JNDI lookup error was due to setting the context when it was not necessary based on the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b15505/access.htm#i1020005)